# Return data while task running

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, locking, task

I have List of objects inside of long running task. List changes all the time. Please, tell me a best way to safe return this list while task running. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more context. The best way to do that is to provide a code example.

Comment: are you able to take global object? may help